# Does PHP repeat variables with the same name in phpMyAdmin, or is it a flaw with print_r?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, phpmyadmin, behavior

I was looking at the results of a mysql join in phpmyadmin, and comparing it to the php print_r dump, and noticed that the print_r seems to only use the first (row)"id" variable it comes to, and skips the second one.  Is there a reason why the print_r wouldn't put something like a 'tablename."id"' instead of just eliminating the second tables "id" value?

PHPmyADMIN head dump:

- id inst_id zip id inst_id skill

PHP sample dump:

- Array ( [id] => 1 [inst_id] => 1 [zip] => 23456 [skill] => meow )

Comment: Technically, if it's an array, you can't have something like Array ( [id] => 1, [id] => 2).

Comment: A key can only appear once in an array.

Comment: You can't have Array ( [id] => 1, [id] => 2) but you can have something like Array ( [id][1] => 1, [id][2] => 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_r` just prints the array as it is, and apparently it only has those 4 indexes with the specified values.

The problem is in the query itself. Table names or table aliases are not returned in the field name, so you get two fields named `id`. Since an array cannot have the same key twice, one of the two is just skipped.

So to solve it, change the query by specifying an alias for the field itself:

```sql
SELECT
  t1.id as t1_id, -- Key will be t1_id
  t2.id as t2_id, -- Key will be t2_id
  .. other fields ..
FROM
  .. etcetera ...
```

Comment: I was just asking about why the two use cases of the same thing act so differently.

Comment: Ah. Well, for an array, the key is a unique index. For a query result that is not the case. You just have a list of fields, and each of them has a name and a value. So two fields can have the same name in the query result. As soon as PHP translates them to an array, the duplicate field names are lost.